# Free quantum particles with space-dependent mass

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation

I'm interested in solving the 1D quantum problem for a free particle with the Hamiltonian

$$H = -\partial_{x}\frac{\hbar^2}{2m(x)}\partial_{x}$$

in the finite interval $x\in\left[0,N\right]$. This problem has probably been solved somewhere, and I'm interested in finding methods for generic, smooth mass functions $m(x)$. The eigenfunctions of this operator should (I think) be smooth deformations of free particle states with constant mass; preliminary numerics for the discretized version of this problem suggest as much. But I'd like to extract the entire spectrum if possible, so if anyone has techniques to recommend for this problem I'd appreciate it.